# why is my page reloading even when i am not calling reload()?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a collapse component which is dynamic list of arrays. However, this collapse component has 3 features as "compare", "edit" and "delete".

Edit routes to a new screen which is working, however compare is a modal (Popup) but the problem is when i click on the icon, flag sets to true but at the same time refresh the screen which makes flag go back to its default value of false, hence popup does not Open. Can someone help me where is the issue? TIA

I tried to invoke shouldComponentUpdate method, but it doesnt help. I am checking boolean state value of visibleModal in which case if its true i return false else i will return true. Although, i am condition becomes true, but i see page getting refreshed.

```
      recipes = data.map((recipe, i) => {
        return  this.state.dataReceived === true ? ( <div>
          <Col span={24}>
            <Collapse accordion>
              <Panel header={recipe.BASELINE_NAME} >
                {recipe.RUN_BASELINE.map((runs) => (
                <div>
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "1em", padding: "0.8em", backgroundColor: "#a09f9f", height: "54px", borderRadius: "5px" }}>
                      <Col span={18}>
                        <Icon type="star" style={{ fontSize: "18px" }} /><a href={hrefdata} id={runs} name={recipe.BASELINE_NAME} style={{ marginTop: "-1em", marginLeft: "1em", color: "#fff", fontSize: "18px",fontFamily: "OpenSans" }} onClick={this.run}><strong>{runs}</strong></a>
                      </Col>
                    <Col span={6}>
                      <div style={{ display: "inline-block", marginLeft: "60%" }}>
                        <a href="" onClick={this.showModalNow} name="swap"><Icon type="swap" style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: "18px" }}></Icon></a>
                        <a href={hrefdata1} onClick={this.showCreate} name="edit" id={runs} name={recipe.BASELINE_NAME}><Icon type="edit" style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: "18px", marginLeft: "1em" }}></Icon></a>
                        <a href="" onClick={this.delete} id={runs} name="dash" ><Icon type="delete" style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: "18px", marginLeft: "1em" }}></Icon></a>
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </div><br></br>
                </div>
                ))}
                <div style={{ borderStyle: "dotted", marginLeft: "1em", padding: "0.5em", height: "54px", borderRadius: "5px" }}>
                  <a href={hrefdata2} onClick={this.create} id={recipe.BASELINE_NAME} title="Create New Scenario"><strong style={{ fontSize: "18px", marginLeft: "1.5em", fontFamily:"OpenSans",color:"#c7c7c7" }}>CREATE NEW SCENARIO</strong></a>
                </div>

              </Panel>
            </Collapse><br></br>
          </Col>
          <Modal
                  visible={this.state.visibleModal}
                  title="Compare Scenario"
                  style={{ top: 20 }}
                  onCancel={this.handleCancelNow}
                  footer={[
                    <Button key="back" onClick={this.handleCancelNow}>Cancel</Button>,
                    <Button key="submit" type="primary"  onClick={this.handleOk} disabled={this.state.flag}>
                      Compare
                    </Button>,
                  ]}
                >
                  <div style={{ marginTop: "6em" }}>
                  </div>
                </Modal>
        </div>) : (<LoadingSpinner message={"Please wait while we load the data.."}/>)
      }
```

Comment: try preventDefault().

Comment: To add to @Atul's comment. Your `Icon`s are wrapped in `<a>` tags which will attempt to navigate somewhere, (even if it's the same page) unless you prevent it from happening. Another solution *might* be to move your `onClick` handling to the `Icon`s themselves. Although there may be accessibility concerns doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `key="submit"` it treats the modal as a form.
But if you really want to use it in , The function `this.handleOk` should be on `onSubmit` prop of form.
`<form onSubmit={e => this.handleOk(e)}>`
then on your `handleOk` function, you should add e.preventDefault(); to prevent the page from reloading.
See the sample below:

```
handleOk = e => {
 //Prevent page reload
 e.preventDefault();
...so on
```

Comment: Correct, also it was also happening when achor tags are used which forces screen to refresh.